# DAX syntax sugar examples

Tags: syntax, powerbi, dax, syntactic-sugar

I just came accross article on  syntax sugar in DAX - https://exceleratorbi.com.au/simple-filters-and-syntax-sugar-in-dax/

1.

Total Sales Syntax Sugar = SUM(Sales[ExtendedAmount])

Total Sales Full Syntax = SUMX(Sales, Sales[ExtendedAmount])

2. Total Sales Prior Year Syntax Sugar =
   CALCULATE(
   [Total Sales],
   SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date])

Total Sales Prior Year Full Syntax =
CALCULATE(
[Total Sales],
DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], -1, YEAR))

3. Total Sales of Bikes Simple =
   CALCULATE(
   [Total Sales],
   Product[Category] = "Bikes")

Total Sales of Bikes Full Version =
CALCULATE(
[Total Sales],
FILTER(
ALL(Product[Category]),
Product[Category] = "Bikes"))

Does anyone know other exampes of syntax sugar in DAX?

Robert

Comment: Many time intelligence functions, like DATESYTD, PREVIOUSMONTH, etc.